# SQL Server: merge two rows of data from same table and save into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to merge two rows of data and save into another table in SQL Server?

Example, I have Table A (Month, Category, AmountBought) with 4 rows of data :

```
- January, Student, 30
- January, Lecturer, 40
- February, Student, 10
- February, Lecturer, 20
```

I want to merge two rows which has same month and save into Table B (Month, AmountOfStudentBought, AmountOfLecturerBought) exactly like below :

```
- January, 30, 40
- February, 10, 20
```

Comment: What have you tried? If you're brand new to SQL, start by looking up how to `JOIN` tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation to do the pivoting:

```
select month,
    sum(case when category = 'Student' then AmountBought else 0 end) as AmountOfStudentBought,
    sum(case when category = 'Lecturer' then AmountBought else 0 end) as AmountOfLecturerBought
from your_table
group by month;
```