# How to merge two or more rows of same table into columns base on some conditions in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the result as merge of two or more rows in the same table based on some conditions.

Table Rows
[image: Query Table]

Here I want to merge the rows with same Trade Head into single row. and we ignore the Interview Location in the Expected Result Merge Format(Below image). and the result table's column count will depend on the Interview Location.

Expected Result Merge Format
[image]

**Explanation On Merge Table**
Here nine columns just because of Welder trade has three interview location. and each location selection count is merged at end.

I have found some solutions like [Using Case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42959843/4075032) , But in my case the data in Trade Head, Interview Locations are not fixed. May be tomorrow one can put ASP.Net Programmer or Software Tester as of their requirement.

Comment: Do you have any ID column in your table which can identify older and newer row in the table for welder and other trade heads?

Comment: And also, Welder can have more than 3 locations? or Maximum 3 location?

Comment: @mkRabbani this is a result set of a query. So we cant set the old and new. and yes welder can have more than 3 locations.

Comment: And that case there may have more than 9 column, right?

Comment: yes, depend on the location and trade the No. of result column will increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following script will work for maximum 3 row. For more row, you need to add more logics in the query per trade head. But as there no id column exists to determine older and newer row between a same Trade Head, values will be put on 9 different column but the order of SelCnt columns and value will be not synchronized. But if there an ID or any auto increment column in the table, everything will just work like a charm.

You can check LIVE Demo [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cf4864b2304166abf5e544dec3bdad4c)

```
WITH CTE([Trade Head], [Select Count On Date 1], [Select Count On Date 2], [Select Count On Date 3],C1,C2,C3)
AS
(
    SELECT [Trade Head], [Select Count On Date 1], [Select Count On Date 2],[Select Count On Date 3],
    CASE    WHEN RN = 1 THEN RN+0   WHEN RN = 2 THEN RN+2   WHEN RN = 3 THEN RN+4 END C1, 
    CASE    WHEN RN = 1 THEN RN+1   WHEN RN = 2 THEN RN+3   WHEN RN = 3 THEN RN+5 END C2, 
    CASE    WHEN RN = 1 THEN RN+2   WHEN RN = 2 THEN RN+4   WHEN RN = 3 THEN RN+6 END C3
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY [Trade Head] 
            ORDER BY [ID]
            -- use ORDER BY [Trade Head] if no ID column exists
        )  RN
        FROM your_table            
    ) A
)

SELECT [Trade Head],
SUM(CASE WHEN C1 = 1 THEN [Select Count On Date 1] ELSE NULL END) SelCnt1,
SUM(CASE WHEN C2 = 2 THEN [Select Count On Date 2] ELSE NULL END) SelCnt2,
SUM(CASE WHEN C3 = 3 THEN [Select Count On Date 3] ELSE NULL END) SelCnt3,
SUM(CASE WHEN C1 = 4 THEN [Select Count On Date 1] ELSE NULL END) SelCnt4,
SUM(CASE WHEN C2 = 5 THEN [Select Count On Date 2] ELSE NULL END) SelCnt5,
SUM(CASE WHEN C3 = 6 THEN [Select Count On Date 3] ELSE NULL END) SelCnt6,
SUM(CASE WHEN C1 = 7 THEN [Select Count On Date 1] ELSE NULL END) SelCnt7,
SUM(CASE WHEN C2 = 8 THEN [Select Count On Date 2] ELSE NULL END) SelCnt8,
SUM(CASE WHEN C3 = 9 THEN [Select Count On Date 3] ELSE NULL END) SelCnt9
FROM CTE
GROUP BY [Trade Head]
```

Answer (score 0):

use aggregation

```
select Thead,max(Selcnt1),max(selcnt2),....max(selcnN) from table
group by Thead
```

Comment: **The 2nd table format is the expected result**. and if we are applying this on the first table we will get only three column in the result.